# How to save additional data in Laravel Socialite/ Social Login?

Tags: database, laravel, momentjs, facebook-login, google-signin

In my project, I am using Laravel Socialite. I am using both Google & Facebook Logins! Anyway, I just want to save some external data alongside the data coming from these social platforms.

What I want to save is the timezone! I am using `moment` so I want to send the timezone with those data using `moment.tz.guess()`!

At the current moment, I am able to save the data coming from Facebook or Google. But how will I be able to save the timezone which is given by a block of JS Code? Please help!